# Error : "Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized."

Tags: asp.net, mysql, data-binding

im getting this error while trying to connect a mysql database to an editor, here is the code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(@"connection string");//tested and working
    conn.Open();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT tes FROM ins");
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(dt);


    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Editor1.Content = dt.Rows[0]["tes"].ToString();
    }
    conn.Close();

}
```

and here is the aspx page code:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">


<cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" Height="400px" Visible="true" />

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</form>
```

what am i doing wrong, thanks in advance.

*i am using asp.net 3.5.*

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Change the line

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT tes FROM ins");
```

To

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT tes FROM ins", conn);
```

And it should work.

Alternatively assign conn to the cmd.Connection property.

The problem with your code is that you never assign a connection to the command, hence the error saying that the connection is not initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT tes FROM ins",conn);
```

or

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT tes FROM ins");
cmd.Connection=conn;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got also this problem. after search the problem found that the object of connection that i have provide SqlDataAdapter is not Initialize so the connection passed as null

Answer (score -1):

Had this same error and simply just forgot the connection in the SQL string as mentioned above.  Just needed to add **con** after the comma.

Comment: This just repeats an existing answer.